# Order by alias column name in dynamic SQL?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, sql-order-by, dynamic-sql

I have a stored procedure in my database. It has dynamic SQL values, and I pick the suitable one based on the parameter I received.

I use alias column names in this procedure. I got error while order values using the alias column names. Below is my procedure.

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[WP_GetVendorPriceList]
    @ItemType        bit,
    @OrderMode       bit,
    @VendorName      varchar(75),
    @OrderBy         varchar(75)
as
Begin 
    DECLARE @QueryVendorName varchar(max), @QueryAllVendorObs varchar(max), @QueryAllVendorNonObs varchar(max), @WhereQuery varchar(max)

    SET @QueryAllVendorNonObs = ';WITH 
    cteForPrice AS (
    Select ItemID, ItemPartNumber, ItemDescription, CreatedDate, InitialPrice, HP As HPPrice, Apple As ApplePrice, Microsoft As MicrosoftPrice, IBM As IBMPrice
    from (select v.ItemID, VendorName, VendorPrice, ItemPartNumber, ItemDescription, CreatedDate, InitialPrice from VendorItemPricing as v left join MasterItems as m on v.ItemID = m.ItemID)A
    PIVOT(MAX(VendorPrice) FOR VendorName IN (HP,Apple,Microsoft,IBM))P),

    cteForDate AS (SELECT ItemID, HP AS HPUpdatedDate, Apple AS AppleUpdatedDate, Microsoft AS MicrosoftUpdatedDate, IBM AS IBMUpdatedDate 
    FROM (SELECT ItemID, VendorName, UpdatedDate FROM VendorItemPricing) A
    PIVOT(MAX(UpdatedDate) FOR Vendorname IN (HP, Apple, Microsoft, IBM))P),

    cteForObsolete AS (
    SELECT ItemID, HP AS HPObsoleteItem, Apple AS AppleObsoleteItem, Microsoft AS MicrosoftObsoleteItem, IBM AS IBMObsoleteItem
    FROM (SELECT Itemid, Vendorname, CAST(ObsoleteItem AS TINYINT) AS INTColumn FROM VendorItemPricing) A
    PIVOT(MAX(INTColumn) FOR Vendorname IN (HP, Apple, Microsoft, IBM)) P)

    SELECT cteForPrice.ItemID, cteForPrice.ItemPartNumber, cteForPrice.ItemDescription,
        CASE
            WHEN HPObsoleteItem = 0 THEN HPPrice
            WHEN AppleObsoleteItem = 0 THEN ApplePrice
            WHEN (IBMObsoleteItem = 0 OR MicrosoftObsoleteItem = 0) AND ISNULL((IBMPrice), 0) > ISNULL((MicrosoftPrice), 0) THEN IBMPrice
            WHEN (IBMObsoleteItem = 0 OR MicrosoftObsoleteItem = 0) AND ISNULL((MicrosoftPrice), 0) > ISNULL((IBMPrice), 0) THEN MicrosoftPrice
        END AS Price,
        CASE
            WHEN HPObsoleteItem = 0 THEN cteForDate.HPUpdatedDate
            WHEN AppleObsoleteItem = 0 THEN cteForDate.AppleUpdatedDate
            WHEN (IBMObsoleteItem = 0 OR MicrosoftObsoleteItem = 0) AND ISNULL((IBMPrice), 0) > ISNULL((MicrosoftPrice), 0) THEN cteForDate.IBMUpdatedDate
            WHEN (IBMObsoleteItem = 0 OR MicrosoftObsoleteItem = 0) AND ISNULL((MicrosoftPrice), 0) > ISNULL((IBMPrice), 0) THEN cteForDate.MicrosoftUpdatedDate
        END AS UpdatedDate
    FROM cteForPrice
    JOIN cteForObsolete ON cteForPrice.ItemID = cteForObsolete.ItemID
    JOIN cteForDate ON cteForPrice.ItemID = cteForDate.ItemID'

    SET @WhereQuery = ' ORDER BY
                        CASE WHEN '''+ @OrderBy +'''=''Price'' AND '+ cast (@OrderMode as varchar(10)) +'= 0 THEN Price END ASC,
                        CASE WHEN '''+ @OrderBy +'''=''Price'' AND '+ cast (@OrderMode as varchar(10)) +'= 1 THEN Price END DESC'

    IF @VendorName != 'All'
    BEGIN
        exec (@QueryVendorName + @WhereQuery)
    END
    ELSE IF @VendorName = 'All' AND @ItemType = 0
    BEGIN
        exec (@QueryAllVendorNonObs + @WhereQuery)
    END
    ELSE IF @VendorName = 'All' AND @ItemType = 1
    BEGIN
        exec (@QueryAllVendorObs + @WhereQuery)
    END
End
```

I was getting this error, whenever I try to execute this procedure.

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 36
>    Invalid column name 'Price'.
>    Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 37
>    Invalid column name 'Price'.

**P.S:** I was getting this error only on dynamic SQL, if I run it without dynamic I have no issues.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
SET @WhereQuery = ' ORDER BY
                    CASE WHEN '''+ @OrderBy +'''=''Price'' AND '+ cast (@OrderMode as varchar(10)) +'= 0 THEN Price END ASC,
                    CASE WHEN '''+ @OrderBy +'''=''Price'' AND '+ cast (@OrderMode as varchar(10)) +'= 1 THEN Price END DESC'
```

to

```
SET @WhereQuery = ' ORDER BY ' +
                    CASE 
                         WHEN @OrderBy = Price AND @OrderMode = 0 THEN 'Price ASC'
                         WHEN @OrderBy = Price AND @OrderMode = 1 THEN 'Price DESC'
                         ELSE '1'
                    END
```

or

```
SET @WhereQuery = ' ORDER BY ' +
                    CASE 
                         WHEN @OrderBy = Price AND @OrderMode = 0 THEN '4 ASC'
                         WHEN @OrderBy = Price AND @OrderMode = 1 THEN '4 DESC'
                         ELSE '1'
                    END
```